# Kafka unable to receive binary data

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to send an audio clip in binary format to a Kafka topic.

But the message is not being received at Kafka.

Following is my producer:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class AudioProducer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
    System.out.println("program started");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "broker-host:9092");
    properties.put("acks", "all");
    properties.put("retries", 0);
    properties.put("batch.size", 26214400);
    properties.put("linger.ms", 1);
    properties.put("buffer.memory", 2*26214400);
    properties.put("max.request.size", 26214400);
    properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
    KafkaProducer<String,byte[]> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, byte[]>(properties);
    try {
        byte[] temp =Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(args[0]));
        System.out.println("input path:"+args[0]);
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String,byte[]>("audio-queue", "test-key",temp ));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    producer.close();
    System.out.println("program completed");
}

}
```

Following is the output with Kafka debug mode:

```
program started
0 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig  - ProducerConfig values: 
    compression.type = none
    metric.reporters = []
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
    acks = all
    batch.size = 26214400
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 10
    bootstrap.servers = [broker-host:9092]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    buffer.memory = 52428800
    timeout.ms = 30000
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    retries = 0
    max.request.size = 26214400
    block.on.buffer.full = true
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    linger.ms = 1
    client.id = 

86 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Metadata  - Updated cluster metadata version 1 to Cluster(nodes = [Node(broker-host, 9092)], partitions = [])
105 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender  - Starting Kafka producer I/O thread.
106 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer  - Kafka producer started
input path:AUD_0030.wav
190 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
190 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Init connection to node -1 for sending metadata request in the next iteration
190 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Initiating connection to node -1 at broker-host:9092.
251 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
261 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Completed connection to node -1
351 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Trying to send metadata request to node -1
361 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Sending metadata request ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, payload=null, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=3,api_version=0,correlation_id=0,client_id=producer-1}, body={topics=[audio-queue]})) to node -1
977 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Metadata  - Updated cluster metadata version 2 to Cluster(nodes = [Node(1, broker-host, 9092)], partitions = [Partition(topic = audio-queue, partition = 0, leader = 1, replicas = [1,], isr = [1,]])
1021 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender  - Beginning shutdown of Kafka producer I/O thread, sending remaining records.
1021 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Initiating connection to node 1 at 01hw508208.india.tcs.com:9092.
1037 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - Completed connection to node 1
11511 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender  - Shutdown of Kafka producer I/O thread has completed.
11512 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer  - The Kafka producer has closed.
program completed
```

But the same topic and the same program works fine with string message.

Also I checked the Kafka logs at broker node. I could find only string messages but not the binary message.

Comment: How big is your file and if it is larger than 1 MB, did you change the broker settings to allow for bigger files?

Comment: Yes, its 1.8 MB. Could you please specify the broker parameters?

Comment: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs max.message.bytes

Comment: @ftr  Thanks ... Able to receive the message...

Comment: @VijayInnamuri would you be willing to share the full working program, please. I am trying to do the same just instead of producer I am trying to build a source connector for audio files, any suggestions are also welcome. thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it solved the problem, I'll phrase my comment as an answer.

Kafka is not a file server and will perform best with message in the kilobyte range. Per default, the maximum message size is 1 MB which can be overwritten by setting the brokers [max.message.bytes](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) property to a higher value .

Doing that also has the consequence that the maximum fetch amount for consumers (in the new consumer API) should be increased via `fetch.max.bytes`

Big messages have performance drawbacks. When sending bigger files, it should be considered to store files on a storage system (e.g. S3) and only pass URIs to those files around in Kafka.